# whitespaces in alltt environment get merged

Tags: beamer, verbatim

```
\begin{frame}{Beispiel Mergesort}
    \begin{alltt}
            mergesort :: (Ord a, Trans a) => [a] -> [a]

            mergesort []   =  []

            mergesort [x]  =  [x]

            mergesort xs   =  sortmerge (process mergesort \# xs1)

                                    (process mergesort \# xs2)

                 where (xs1,xs2) = unshuffle xs
    \end{alltt}
\end{frame}
```

I'm doing a beamer presentation and try to display some source code, but I'm loosing all intendation, all whitespaces get merged into a single space. (not only at the beginning of the lines, but also around the '=' characters)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can someone help?

Cheers,

Lukas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I guess you want `\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Beispiel Mergesort}`

Answer (score 2):

Frames containing verbatim material should be declared `fragile`; also you don't really want that dramatic indentation, which will be kept in the listing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Beispiel Mergesort}
\begin{alltt}
mergesort :: (Ord a, Trans a) => [a] -> [a]

mergesort []   =  []

mergesort [x]  =  [x]

mergesort xs   =  sortmerge (process mergesort \# xs1)

                      (process mergesort \# xs2)

    where (xs1,xs2) = unshuffle xs
\end{alltt}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I think it is better to use the `\frametitle` command rather than an additional argument to `\begin{frame}`.

[image]

Instead of `alltt` you can use the `semiverbatim` environment, which doesn't require an additional package, but still requires `[fragile]`.

Comment: thanks! Actually the tabs in front of the line don't seem to matter, those get killed by tex, just the intendation using spaces is kept. So I keep my tabs and get a nice looking tex code ;-) Thank you =)

Comment: @Whadupapp In order my files *don't* have any TAB character, my editor does exactly nothing when the TAB key is hit.